# RxJava custom exception handling/propagation in spring boot rest application

Tags: java, spring, rest, rx-java

I am wondering what is the best with RxJava and spring REST API?

I have a simple REST service and in the repository, in case of an error, I'd like to propagate a specific custom error to the client. But I am not sure how to map different custom exceptions with RxJava.

Here is a call to the backend:

```
private Single<Customer> findCustomerById(long customerId) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> getRestTemplate().getForObject(
            MyBackendService.SEARCH_CUSTOMER_BY_ID.getUrl(),
            Customer.class, customerId))
            .onErrorResumeNext(ex -> Single.error(new BackendException(ex)));
}
```

My exception:

```
public class BackendException extends Exception {
public BackendException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public BackendException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}
```

So the question is how to map/propagate with **RxJava**  this `BackendException` to let's say `NotFound` (404) or `InternalServerError` (500)?

Answer (score 0):

I've used exception libraries that have exceptions for each type of HTTP response that you [care about](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) and a canonical error class that can be put into the body of an HTTP Response and easily parsed by a REST client, i.e, something with a code and a message.

As for translating exceptions to different HTTP responses, that depends on the version of Spring and REST library you're using. There are various ways to do that documented [here](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring), [here](https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-spring-rest) and [here](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html).

The fact that you're using RxJava doesn't matter so much in determining your approach. I have used similar `onErrorResumeNext` code to what you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJava subscription mechanism to handle errors, use `onErrorResumeNext` to return values and not exceptions. I would do something like this:

```
//The web service call is just this
private Single<Customer> findCustomerById(long customerId) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() ->
                    getRestTemplate().getForObject(MyBackendService.SEARCH_CUSTOMER_BY_ID.getUrl(),
                            Customer.class,
                            customerId));
    }
...

//Then just manage the exception on the subscription
findCustomerById(long customerId)
    .subscribe(customer -> {
        //Write the success logic here
        System.out.println(customer);
    }, throwable -> {
        //Manage the error, for example
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    });
```

Hope it helps...